# Java Applet/Robot Keycode Mismatch

Tags: java, applet, keycode, awtrobot

I am feeding the key from KeyUp()/KeyDown() in an applet to a Robot's KeyPress()/keyRelease() through UDP to "synchronize" the inputs of two users. However, the key codes appear to be mismatched - A "k" on the client end produces a "+" on the server end. Is there some way to convert between the two types?

Solved - I wasn't using a KeyListener, just native applet methods, so it wasn't using VK constants.

Comment: What are you sending exactly?  Do you have some sample code?

Comment: I sent the key code passed to KeyUp/Down as an int. The problem isn't that the number changes (it doesn't) but that the two sets of codes don't always correspond.

Comment: The virtual keys shouldn't be different between the systems, as they are defined in the event.  How are you converting the key code back to a char?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (or perhaps more accurately, 2 SSCCEs - 1 of the applet, the other of the servlet ..whatever on the server side).

Comment: Solved - I wasn't using a KeyListener, just native applet methods, so it wasn't using VK constants.